# Simple Command for Cron Job that will FTPS a Text File to Remote Server

Tags: ftps, lftp

I am trying to have a text file moved routinely from our server to a remote server. The remote server requires ftps protocol and our servers IP address to be whitelisted (which I have done). The best I have come up with is:

lftp -c 'set ftp:ssl-allow true ; set ssl:verify-certificate no; open -u USERNAME,PASSWORD -e "cd /; mput test.csv; quit" ftps.bol.com'

Remote server = ftps.bol.com
Text file = test.csv

When I run this via SSH terminal I just get a never ending "[Connecting...]"

Any ideas what is wrong or how I can trouble shoot?

Comment: Should I be using wput in rather than lftp?

Comment: Can you telnet (or the *nix equivalent) to your host on the ftps port (22 afaik)? Can you connect to the FTP site OK using a GUI FTP client?

Comment: Good shout. The nc -v showed that, where I could get a response from my whitelisted IP local machine, the server could not  (on port 22). I have applied again for the server IP address to be whitelisted.